# wowza authontication using external jar

Tags: java, authentication, jar, wowza

I am using Wowza streaming engine in my project. I successfully started wowza with basic authentication. I need to authenticate wowza with my database because I am creating a java project. It will handle the authentication process after I add the jar to the Wowza engine lib folder.

This is the source code of jar:

```
 public class WowzaTesting {
    boolean authStatus = false;
    public boolean authenticationTest(String username, String password) {
        System.out.println("Authentication Process started");

        // authentication code here
        // if authentication is done authStatus=true; else authStatus=false;

        if (authStatus) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have added to conf file:

```
<Module>
  <Name>TestWowza</Name>
  <Description>Java code for testing wowza</Description>
  <Class>com.test.wowza.WowzaTesting</Class>
</Module>
```

Then restarted wowza server engine.

I have some questions:

1. Have I missed any steps?
2. How to call method in the jar file in the time of Wowza authentication?

Currently I am using this command for live streaming"

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://localhost:port/livetest" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f rtsp "rtsp://username:password@localhost:port/live/livetest
```

3. How to get the username and password from the above command to my method?

Answer (score 0):

> Have I missed any steps?

Wowza API has the AuthenticateUsernamePasswordProviderBase class that you would need to extend in order to integrate database authentication.

> How to call method in the jar file in the time of Wowza authentication?

The way that RTSP authentication currently works in Wowza is that you specify the authentication method to be used in the Application configuration (in the Root/Application/RTP/Authentication/PublishMethod section of the file). These publish methods are defined in the Authentication configuration. To intercept this with your custom authentication module, you would need to add your Java class to this Authentication.xml file as a property. In version 3 of Wowza, the Authentication.xml file is in the conf/ directory and can be easily edited, but in version 4, this has been bundled into the com.wowza.wms.conf package (you can grab a copy from the package and copy it to your conf/ folder and it will override the one in the package). Wowza will thus use the method defined in your class instead of the built-in ones.

> How to get the username and password from the above command to my method?

When Wowza receives the incoming RTSP connection, it should query the username/password from the connection and pass these to your Java class to handle authentication.

An example code that integrates a database for authentication is below:

```
package com.wowza.wms.example.authenticate;

import com.wowza.wms.authentication.*;
import com.wowza.wms.logging.WMSLoggerFactory; 
import java.sql.*;

public class AuthenticateUsernamePasswordProviderExample extends AuthenticateUsernamePasswordProviderBase
{
public String getPassword(String username)
{
    // return password for given username       
    String pwd = null;

    WMSLoggerFactory.getLogger(null).info("Authenticate getPassword username: " + username);

    Connection conn = null;
    try 
    {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/wowza?user=root&password=mypassword");

        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try 
        {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT pwd FROM users where username = '"+username+"'");
            while (rs.next())
            {
                pwd = rs.getString("pwd");
            }

        } 
        catch (SQLException sqlEx) 
        {
            WMSLoggerFactory.getLogger(null).error("sqlexecuteException: " + sqlEx.toString());
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (rs != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    rs.close();
                } 
                catch (SQLException sqlEx) 
                {

                    rs = null;
                }
            }

            if (stmt != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    stmt.close();
                } 
                catch (SQLException sqlEx) 
                {
                    stmt = null;
                }
            }
        }

        conn.close();
    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
        // handle any errors
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    }

    return pwd;
}

public boolean userExists(String username)
{
    // return true is user exists
    return false;
}
}
```